# Storing Read/Write app data for all users on macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, core-foundation

I have a macOS application should be registered for all users on that physical machine. I'm currently using nsuserdefaults to store the registration info, but this prevents other users of the machine from using the software, because nsuserdefaults is user-specific.

I've looked into using the CFPreferences API:

```
 CFPreferencesSetValue(key,
                      value,
                      kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication,
                      kCFPreferencesAnyUser,
                      kCFPreferencesCurrentHost);
```

But that requires root privileges, which I do not want to require for my application.

What is the best way to store registration info for all users of a machine, without requiring root privileges?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to create a folder in `/Library/Application Support` that anyone can write to in the postinstall script in my installer package.  Then the application can do whatever it likes in that folder and in fact, like you, I use it primarily to store registration information.

The folder should be named as your application's bundle ID and your installer package needs to be set to run as root so that postinstall can create the folder in the first place.

If you don't yet have an installer package, you will have to make one.  For this, I recommend [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html).  Avoid Apple's Package Maker tool - it's terrible.